# CircuitTikZ splitting input into two gates

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have LaTeX code using the [`CircuitTikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz) package for drawing a simple logic circuit, but I'm not convinced that my code is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do. Essentially, I have two inputs that each need to go to two gates. Here's what the code looks like:

```
    \begin{circuitikz} \draw
        (2,1) node[or port] (myor) {}
        (2,-1) node[nand port] (mynand) {}
        (4,0) node[and port] (myand) {}
        (myor.out) -| (myand.in 1)
        (mynand.out) -| (myand.in 2)

        (0,1) |- (myor.in 1)
        (0,1) |- (mynand.in 1)
        (-1,0) to[short, -*] (0,0)

        (0,-1) -| (myor.in 2)
        (0,-1) -| (mynand.in 2)
        (-1,-1) to[short, -*] (0.62,-1)
    ;\end{circuitikz}
```

Output:

[image]

The output looks correct, but I don't feel very good about the last line where I draw to `(0.62,-1)`. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your circuit is OK. Another option to draw the final lines would be to place coordinates along a path and then use this coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{circuitikz} \draw
        (2,1) node[or port] (myor) {}
        (2,-1) node[nand port] (mynand) {}
        (4,0) node[and port] (myand) {}
        (myor.out) -| (myand.in 1)
        (mynand.out) -| (myand.in 2)

        (myor.in 1) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- (mynand.in 1) coordinate[pos=0.33] (a)
        (a) to[short, *-]  (-1,0|-a)

        (myor.in 2) |- (mynand.in 2) coordinate[pos=0.43] (b)
        (b) to[short, *-] (-1,0|-b)
    ;\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that, for example,

```
  (0,1) |- (myor.in 1)
  (0,1) |- (mynand.in 1)
  (-1,0) to[short, -*] (0,0)
```

was replaced with

```
(myor.in 1) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- (mynand.in 1) coordinate[pos=0.33] (a)
(a) to[short, *-]  (-1,0|-a)
```

and

```
(0,-1) -| (myor.in 2)
(0,-1) -| (mynand.in 2)
(-1,-1) to[short, -*] (0.62,-1)
```

was replaced with

```
(myor.in 2) |- (mynand.in 2) coordinate[pos=0.43] (b)
(b) to[short, *-] (-1,0|-b)
```

and in both cases I used the perpendicular coordinate system, where, for example `(-1,0|-b)` means the x-coordinate of `(-1,0)` and the y-coordinate of `(b)`.